# Prove the triangle inequality definition of norm for $||(x,y,z)|| = |x| + 2(y^2 + z^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Here is what I got so far:

$$||(x,y,z)+(a,b,c)|| = ||(x+a,y+b,z+c)|| = |x+a| + 2((y+b)^2 + (z+c)^2)^{1/2} ≤ |x|+|a| + 2((y+b)^2 + (z+c)^2)^{1/2} = |x|+|a| + 2(y^2 +2yb +b^2 + z^2 + 2zc + c^2)^{1/2}$$

I don't know how to take it from here. I'd appreciate any hints or help regarding this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge of TeX.

Comment: I'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $||(x,y,z)|| = |x| + 2 ||(y,z)||_2$. (*)

Thus, $||(x,y,z)+(a,b,c)|| = ||(a+x,y+b,z+c)|| = |a+x| + 2 ||(y+b,z+c)||_2$. $(* *)$

By the triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$, $|a+x| \leq |a|+|x|$. By the triangle inequality for the 2-norm, $||(y+b,z+c)||_2 \leq ||(y,z)||_2 + ||(b,c)||_2$.

Using these inequalities with the right hand of $(**)$ and noting the definition of the norm (*) for $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$, you can finish the proof.

Comment: how would the unit ball of this norm look like?

Comment: You can easily put that into Wolfram Alpha or something to see what the unit sphere looks like.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $M$ is a norm on $U$, $N$ a norm on $V$, and $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are positive real numbers, then $Q$ defined on $W=U\times V$ by
$$
Q(u,v)=\lambda M(u)+\mu N(v),
$$
is a norm on $W$. Apply this to $\lambda=1$, $\mu=2$, $M$ the absolute value on $U=\mathbb R$ and $N$ the $\ell^2$-norm on $V=\mathbb R^2$.

One can even compose $M$ and $N$ through a third norm $P$ on $\mathbb R^2$, that is, consider $Q$ defined by
$$
Q(u,v)=P(M(u),N(v)).
$$

Comment: How would the unit ball for this norm look like?

Comment: Like the set of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $|x| + 2(y^2 + z^2)^{1/2}=1$.

Comment: Geometrically speaking one has two truncated straight cones of height $1$ joined by their bases, each a disk of radius $1/\sqrt2$.